# IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model

Tags: database, intellij-idea, pojo

How can I generate entity (POJO) from database model using IntelliJ IDEA 10. I create "Data source" in IntelliJ but I have not any idea how can I generate the POJO.

Answer (score 145):

**UPDATE:**
In IntelliJ 16 this feature in now implemented.
The steps to do it are:

1. **Database** view context menu
2. Scripted Extensions
3. Generate POJOs

---

You can read more here:
[Feature request: allow "generate classes from database schema" for plain-JDBC developers](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66037)

---

**Note:**
The following information is about version 15 and earlier:

First, you need to tell IntelliJ that you are using Hibernate (I guess you are if you need the orm POJO of the table)

1. Go to "Project structure"
   (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
2. In "Project settings" select "Modules"
3. Press <kbd>+</kbd> and add the Hibernate facet in your module.

Now that you have set up your hibernate configuration facet, you can extract your POJOs.

1. At your bottom right horizontal panel, you will now see a tab called
   "Persistence" (ιf you can't find Persistence tab you may show it by choosing View > Tool Windows > Persistence)
2. There you can right-click on the hibernate icon named like your module
3. Go to "Generate Persistence Mapping"-"by database schema"
4. Now I guess you can find your way...
5. In general, settings select the datasource that you want to use and now you
   can see all the tables in your datasource object
6. Now you can do many things, add relationships with the + sign, change the
   name and type of the POJO's properties etc.
   note: if you get an error and the "OK" is disabled its probably because the data
   type that IntelliJ found for your POJO is invalid. Just change it to the one
   you need and you are ready to go!

Comment: Also JPA facet can be used as well

Comment: @zpontikas I dont get hibernate or jpa facet option in intellij idea 12.1.3. Do I need to do anything to get that ?

Comment: These facets are available in the Ultimate version only

Comment: Many thanks. All I can add: if you can't find Persistence tab or panel mentioned in step 1, you may show it by choosing View > Tool Windows > Persistence.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski thanks. I added that to the answer just in case some1 gets lost

Comment: This approach gets you a hibernate dependency. The question was how to create a POJO, not how attach your project to a framework!

Comment: This WAS the easiest way to generate a POJO up to version 16(15?). Now with version 16 onwards you can use the "Generate POJOs" script descriped in the "UPDATE" section

Comment: i click on it and nothing happens

Comment: It is after "now I guess you can find your way" that It fails for me. I select the source and the tables.  Then it wants "mapping XML" or "JPA annotations".  When I select mappings XML I cannot enter a directory.  When I select Annotation it wants a session factory, when I try to add a session factory it complains there is no source root, but there is one.  It also says it wants a "persistence unit" whatever that is.  If I select separate XML per entity it says it does the OR generation but then nothing gets generated.

Answer (score 8):

The default [Scripted Extensions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-66037) `Generate POJOs.groovy` is not very good when dealing with tables with underscore(which is very common).

So I make some modifications.

The main code

```
def calcFields(DasObject table) {
    DasUtil.getColumns(table).reduce([]) { fields, col ->
        def spec = Case.LOWER.apply(col.dataType.specification)
        def typeStr = typeMapping.find { p, t -> p.matcher(spec).find() }.value
        fields += [[
                       name : javaName(col.name, false),
                       type : typeStr,
                       annos: """
    /**
     * $col.comment
     */"""]]
    }
}

static String javaName(String str, boolean capitalize) {
    def s = CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, str);
    capitalize || s.length() == 1 ? s : Case.LOWER.apply(s[0]) + s[1..-1]
}
```

You can find the whole gist here https://gist.github.com/aristotll/ad799a7462e8b705b26103944cca24a6

Answer (score 2):

If you have Intellij Idea and Jpa Buddy installed you can do this by

Database -> table -> right clicking -> Generate Persistence Mapping

choose table and package path ok

[image]