# Automatic generation of database model class in spring

Tags: database, spring, orm

Is there any tool/way for automatic generation of model class of database tables? For example in Xcode can generate data classes from database model in core data. Is there anything similar in spring?

PS. I'm using IntelliJ Idea and MySql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in IntelliJ too, you can generate Model classes from database model, you can refer this [Generate Model classes from database model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have a look a JPA (Java Persistence API) and the examples Spring offers you: http://spring.io/search?q=JPA