# IntelliJ IDEA 15 generate orm pojo of the table for hibernate

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, orm

I am a beginner to hibernate and want to generate orm pojo of the table for hibernate in Intellij idea 15. there is a good solution provided in [IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model). but I can't find where is `Generate Persistence Mapping` window in Intellij idea 15.

[this is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gie8T.png), where is `Generate Persistence Mapping`? Anyone can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my IJ14 it's a pop-up menu item, as it also seems to be explained in the link where you've got the idea from.

Try right-clicking the `tutorial` item in the tree from the `Persistence` tool window, then at the bottom (or somewhere) you should see `Generate persistence mapping`:

[image: Generate persistence mapping]

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my question. I can't find the `Generate Persistence Mapping` because the the screen is not height enough.

Comment: after generate the entity code successfully, `catalog = ""  ` show error in `@Table(name = "*******", schema = "*****", catalog = "")`  upon every entity class, the error info is `Cannot resolve catalog '', This inspection controls whether the Persistence ORM annotations are checked against configured Datasource`

Comment: @sachin In order to make IJ validate the annotations against the alreay present DB structure, you need to [add a database connection/data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/managing-data-sources.html) from the database too-window, and [assign it to the persistence unit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/associating-data-sources-with-session-factories-and-persistence-units.html) with the same popup-menu from the gif above, see second item.