# Gererating Hibernate Entiry classes from data source in Intellij Ultmate edition

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, pojo

I'm following the steps in the below link to generate Hibernate Entity classes. 
I'm suck with step 1. Not able to find persistence tool window. Even in View > Tool Windows > Persistence.

Using Intellij Ultimate edition - 2016.1.3
What am I missing?

[IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue.
Hibernate plugin was not enabled.

File -> Settings -> plugins -> search for "Hibernate support" and select the same.
Save and exit and follow the steps in the other window. It just works!!