# How to generate automatically relationships with JPA with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I found this solution for a problem I have: how to generate entities with JPA annotations from a given database.

[IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model)

Now with IntelliJ I'm given the possibility to **create relationships between entities manually**. Is there a way to generate them **automatically** as it did with entities? 
I used the `REFERENCES` keyword when needed while creating the database. I suppose there should be an automatic mapping of relationships as well!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [Generating entities from DB Schema](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#generate_entities_and_mappings) in [dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-persistence-mapping-import-dialogs.html) there is an option to 'Show default relationships' which when selected will display FK relationships when selecting tables to generate entities from:
[image]