# Adding POJOs from database in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

How to auto generate POJOs from database tables along with the relations, @OneToOne, @OneToMany etc. The default generator generates the POJOs but not the relationships. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46235745/8958060

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate automatically relationships with JPA with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219547/how-to-generate-automatically-relationships-with-jpa-with-intellij)